# Getting ordered coordinates out of ConvexHullRegion

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm trying to get the *ordered* coordinates of a convex hull using `MeshCoordnates[ConvexHullMesh[data]]`, but the coordinates are uselessly out of order:

```
With[{d = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}]},
 ListPlot[
  d,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  Epilog -> Polygon[MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[d]]]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

The older ComputationalGeometry`ConvexHull function works correctly:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
With[{d = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}]},
 ListPlot[
  d,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  Epilog -> {Opacity[0.2], Polygon[d[[ConvexHull[d]]]]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Is there some way to get the ordered coordinates from ConvexHullMesh?

Edit: I need to manipulate the polygon; the goal is not to just display the graphics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For graphing, my preferred approach is posted already by user21.

To get the ordered coordinates you can reorder `MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[d]` using `FindCurvePath`:

```
With[{d = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}]}, mc=MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[d]];
ListPlot[ d, AspectRatio -> 1, Prolog -> {Yellow,Polygon[mc[[FindCurvePath[mc][[1]]]]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

An alternative way to get the ordering of the coordinates is to use the `"BoundaryVertices"` property of `ConvexHullMesh[d]`:

```
ConvexHullMesh[d]["BoundaryVertices"]
```

> {1,8,4,5,6,3,10,9,2,7,11,1}

which is a rotated version of

```
FindCurvePath[MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[d]]][[1]]
```

> {4,5,6,3,10,9,2,7,11,1,8,4}

And, the property `"Coordinates"` can be used instead of `MeshCoordinates`; so

```
#["Coordinates"][[#["BoundaryVertices"][[1]]]]&@ConvexHullMesh[d]
```

gives the ordered coordinates.

```
d = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}];
chcoords=#["Coordinates"][[#["BoundaryVertices"][[1]]]]&@ConvexHullMesh[d];
ListPlot[ d, AspectRatio -> 1, Prolog -> {Yellow,Polygon[chcoords]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Yet another way to get the ordered coordinates is to get the `"GraphicsComplex"` property and extract

```
Cases[Normal@ConvexHullMesh[d]["GraphicsComplex"],Polygon[x_]:>x,Infinity][[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `FindCurvePath`. I wonder if the ComputationalGeometryPackage uses that internally, or if it has a more direct and efficient approach (assuming `FindCurvePath` is somewhat expensive?).

Comment: @ZachB, Thank you for the accept. I am not familiar with the `ComputationalGeometry` package, but we should be able to see the code for `ConvexHull` function.

Comment: @ZachB, you can see the code for `ConvexHull` using `nb = NotebookOpen[
   ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Packages", 
     "ComputationalGeometry"}, "ComputationalGeometry.m"]];
NotebookFind[nb, "compute 2D convex hull using Graham's scan \
algorithm"]`

Comment: When I copy you code I find a some parenthesis out of sync also added a more efficient way then FindPath

Comment: @user21, thank you; i added the missing `{`.

Comment: Hi, kglr. `ConvexHullMesh` does not have properties like "BoundaryVertices" at least in 13.2. So this answer needs an update.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the goal is to create the graphics:

```
With[{d = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}]},
 Show[ListPlot[d, AspectRatio -> 1], ConvexHullMesh[d]]]
```

[image]

And here is a more efficient version than `FindPath`:

```
With[{d = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}]}, 
 ListPlot[d, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Epilog -> 
     GraphicsComplex[
      MeshCoordinates[#], {Opacity[0.2], MeshCells[#, {2, All}]}] &[
   ConvexHullMesh[d]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, just clarified in question -- I actually need the points that comprise the polygon so I can manipulate the hull, so the goal is not (immediately) to create the graphics.

Comment: @ZachB, added a more efficient version.

Comment: Thanks, wish I could select multiple answers. +1'ed.

Comment: @ZachB, no worries, I am no a hunter-gatherer any longer ;-)

Answer (score 7):

```
d = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}];
hull = ConvexHullMesh[d];
```

The ordering can be obtained directly using `MeshCells`:

```
MeshCells[hull, 2]
(* {Polygon[{2, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1}]} *)
```

So:

```
points = MeshCoordinates[hull];
order = MeshCells[hull, 2][[1, 1]];
Graphics[{Yellow, Polygon[points[[order]]], Black, Point[d]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Another good answer, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {20, 2}];
mesh = ConvexHullMesh[pts]
```

You can simple use [`MeshPrimitives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshPrimitives.html).

```
MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]
(* {Polygon[{{0.135494, 0.556868}, {0.147549, 0.121726}, 
             {0.423421, 0.0565637}, {0.894244, 0.172512}, 
             {0.917483, 0.413526}, {0.911708, 0.8986}, 
             {0.708881, 0.866828}, {0.272797, 0.654125}}]} *)
```

A 2D convex hull mesh will consist of a single `Polygon`.  Coordinates are easy to extract from there.

[`MeshCells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCells.html) does the same, but uses point indices instead of point coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

using [`ConvexHullRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullRegion.html)

```
d = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 2}];
ConvexHullRegion[d]
First@ConvexHullRegion[d]
```

gives

[image]